# Automatic conversion MySQL datetime to milliseconds on Apollo client?

Tags: mysql, react-apollo

I am using Apollo server and Apollo React client. The server runs a query against the MySQL database. In GraphQL schema I have defined the corresponding field sampleTime as String in the type Session. (There is no Date type in GraphQL.) But apparently some kind of default conversion is made on the way between the Apollo server and the result of useQuery. The field sampleTime shows the value as a number and not as a string. The number is apparently the JavaScript Date object.

In this case I don't need such a conversion. I found a solution on the server side by converting the SELECT output to the formatted string.

But why this conversion does occur at all?

Thanks